# The ordered pair that a function is represented by

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let x = $\{1,2,3,4\}$. And let  $f\colon x \longrightarrow\mathcal{P}(x)$ be defined as…

$f(1) = \{1,2,3\}$

$f(2) = \{1,4\}$

$f(3) = \emptyset$

$f(4) = \{1,4\}$

I need to determine what ordered pairs the function represents. I know that a set of ordered pairs is a function when the first members of each pair are different. So, I'm thinking that the set will contain four ordered pairs whose first members one of which has 1 as a first member, another which has 2 as its first member, and so on.

But I'm not sure what the second member would be. I feel like the second member of the ordered pair is the function's output but I'm not sure if I can have a component of an ordered pair be a set?

Does anyone have advice about how to go about answering this question? Tips, comments, etc.?

Comment: In a function, the ordered pair $(a,b)$ represents the fact that when you put $a$ into the function, the output is $b$; that is, $(a,b)$ is an element of the set of ordered pairs if and only if $f(a)=b$. So for example, the fact that the image of $3$ is $\varnothing$ tells you that the pair $(3,\varnothing)$ should be an element of the set of pairs that represents the function.

Answer (score 1):

You started just fine. Indeed, the four ordered pairs that you're after are $(1,\{1,2,3\})$, $(2,\{1,4\})$, $(3,\emptyset)$, and $(4,\{1,4\})$.